# How can I use a library that is not on crates.io?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, crate, dnp3

I want to use this library: https://github.com/stepfunc/dnp3, but it is not on crates.io, it only has a repository and I can't implement it. I tried to add it to my `Cargo.toml` like `[dependencies] dnp3 = "0.9.1"` but it says that it does not exist, and indeed it does not have a crate. Inside the repository, it has some examples in `dnp3/example` that have `use dnp3;` as if it were a crate.

How can I use this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can directly specify a Github (or any other git repository) as the source of the dependency.

```
[dependencies]
dnp3 = { git = "https://github.com/stepfunc/dnp3" }
```

See the Cargo reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories

Comment: Thank you! I will try it right now

Comment: thanks a lot! It worked perfect, from now on I will read the documentation better

Answer (score 5):

You can specify dependencies as Git repositories.

```
[dependencies]
dnp3 = { git = "https://github.com/stepfunc/dnp3" }
```

If you want to specify a branch (assuming you do not want to use `main`/`master`), you can add a `branch` key to the declaration above:

```
[dependencies]
dnp3 = { git = "https://github.com/stepfunc/dnp3", branch = "feature/rustls" }
```

Related read: [Specifying dependencies from git repositories](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html)

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it would be to clone the repository and use a dependency with a local path.

```
[dependencies]
dnp3 = { path = "../dnp3" }
```

Related rust [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies)

But of course as other answers mentioned using the git version is better in your case.

Comment: this is also very useful! Thank you so much